# Rails cache_key returning different values before and after model.reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm on Rails 4.2.8.

Let's say I have a model `Contact`, being `contact = Contact.new`.

Calling `contact.cache_key` returns a timestamped key, like so:

"contacts/2615608-20180109154442000000000"

Where `2615608` is the ID and `20180109154442000000000` the timestamp.

I'm seeing a weird behavior in my controller.

After a `contact.update(contact_params)`, if I call `contact.cache_key` I'm having a different timestamp then if I call `contact.reload.cache_key`.

The weird thing is I'm 100% sure no other update is happening to the model's `updated_at` (saying so by checking console's SQL update statements, there is only one call that is changing the `updated_at`)

It's so weird that if I do something like this in the controller:

```
contact.udpate(contact_params)
Rails.logger.info "Updated_at before reload is #{@contact.updated_at} and it's cache_key is #{@contact.cache_key}"
Rails.logger.info "Updated_at after reload is #{@contact.reload.updated_at} and it's cache_key is #{@contact.reload.cache_key}"
```

The output reveals IDENTICAL updated_at values, but different cache_key values:

```
Updated_at before reload is 2018-01-09 14:01:58 -0200 and it's cache_key is contacts/2615608-20180109160158143423000
Updated_at after reload  is 2018-01-09 14:01:58 -0200 and it's cache_key is contacts/2615608-20180109160158000000000
```

As you can see, same updated_at, but different timestamps.

This is driving me nuts. I hate having to manually .reload models without necessity. Why is this happening? Tried looking at cache_key's source code but couldn't find an answer there, since it apparently only depends on the updated_at value (which is the same).

Comment: Are there any callbacks defined on your model (`before_` or `after_`)? Does you database have any triggers defined that might be changing `updated_at`? To me it seems like there's somehow a loss of precision between what Rails thinks its storing and what is actually persisted in the database. What's the type of `updated_at`? What DB are you using?

Comment: @DerekPrior thanks for the attempt but I found out it was a Rails bug. Check my answer bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the issue. **It was a Rails bug, fixed in Rails 5.0.**

The source code for `.cache_key` for Rails 4.2 can be found [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6b0e834a194d112585f41deba0a40780d68e38c6/activerecord/lib/active_record/integration.rb). As you can see, it used `cache_timestamp_format = :nsec`, which was too precise.

The reason I could understand is that, BEFORE the reload, the model's updated_at is still **in memory**, so it has enough resolution (in memory) to return a very precise nanosecond key. But after `model.reload`, the `updated_at` comes from the database, which doesn't have that high resolution, so that's why the cache_key timestamp results in a different number, with a lot of zeroes at the end (in my example, 20180109160158**000000000**).

[This issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/21815) details the problem with the too precise (nanosecond) timestamp, and [this pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/21883) was merged to fixed the issue, changing the precision from :nsec to :usec.

On [the issue discussion](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/21815) (same link above) @tarzan makes a suggestion to fix it by creating an `ActiveSupport::Concern` with the following code:

```
  included do
    self.cache_timestamp_format = :usec
  end
```

and defined the :usec as a formatter in an initializer:

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:usec] = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S%6N"
```

And manually inserting your concern into the models you want to use `.cache_key` manually (by the way, I'm using this method as recommended by the oficial Rails guides for low level caching, by using `Rails.cache.fetch(self.cache_key)`, check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html in topic 1.6 Low-Level Caching).

The problem is, in my tests at least (MySQL on Mac Os High Sierra), being contact a scaffolded model, the precision of :datetime column (like updated_at) is only in the seconds level; that's why his fix doesn't solve it for us since changing from nanoseconds to microseconds precision will still result in two different cache_keys, with less zeroes added to it. As an example:

```
[4] pry(#<ContactsController>)> ::Time::DATE_FORMATS[:usec] = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S%6N"
=> "%Y%m%d%H%M%S%6N"
[5] pry(#<ContactsController>)> @contact.updated_at.utc.to_s(:usec)
=> "20180109234014062142"
[6] pry(#<ContactsController>)> @contact.reload.updated_at.utc.to_s(:usec)
  Contact Load (2.2ms)  SELECT  `contacts`.* FROM `contacts` WHERE `contacts`.`id` = 2615608 LIMIT 1 /*application:Temporadalivre,controller:contacts,action:toggle_status*/
=> "20180109234014000000"
```

So, for now, at least, I'm sticking to the .reload unfortunately.

Lastly but now least, I only realized this bug because we had a page of 20 of these contacts that could be manipulated via ajax. Each ajax call would call `.update` on the model, and return the model `.as_cached_json` to the view. Since `.as_cached_json` was called, we hoped that by reloading the page everything would be already cached, but it wasn't, and only by checking the cache keys we discovered this bug, which gave us a really nice performance boost that we were loosing.